# How can I make a new release on my android app if i lost my keystore?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I run 2 command

> keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks

This command create keystore.jks. Export the certificate for that key to PEM format (upload_certificatie.pem). I will attach upload_certificatie.pem and reply Googleplay developer support to reset the upload key for my app.

> keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125

This command create my-upload-key.keystore that will be placed in the ./android/app folder in my react native project.

I lost my old my-upload-key.keystore. Will the above commands help me keep updating my app? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. When you loose your keystore you cannot make updates to that application. You will have to make a new application in the play store.

Your only other option is to make a new keyfile and contact google support.

https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/recover-your-lost-android-keystore-file-633c853bd11f

You can create a keyfile with the following command (Keystore and JKS are basically the same):

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can the command below create the file my-upload-key.keystore compatible with the keystore.jks above?